# Disable validation for customer address in create customer account

Tags: module, magento-1, customer, customer-address

I need to disable validation for few customer address fields in customer/account/create/ (but only on this page).

Seems like I've messed up with names and can't find out how to fix my code.
Folder structure:

```
Mycompany
|__Mymodule
   |__controllers
      |__Customer
         |__AccountController.php
   etc
   |__config.xml
   Model
   |__Customer
      |__Address.php
      |__Customer.php
```

config.xml

```
...
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <mycompany_mymodule_customer_account_create>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/create/$#]]></from>
            <to>/mymodule/customer_account/create</to>
        </mycompany_mymodule_customer_account_create>
        <excellence_address_customer_account_createPost>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/createPost/$#]]></from>
            <to>/mymodule/customer_account/createPost</to>
        </mycompany_mymodule_customer_account_createPost>
    </rewrite>
    <models>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <customer>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Customer_Customer</customer>
                <address>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Customer_Address</address>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
...
etc
```

The `validate()` function will be overridden in Address.php

```
public function validate()
{
   // my validation 
}
```

By filling form under customer/account/create/, even if I've removed 'required' class in form and removed in customer_register_address **customer_form_attribute** for every attribute_id I don't need @ registration page (e.g. street, city etc.), I still got validation warning message:

```
Please enter the street.
Please enter the city.
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is true for Magento 1.9 but I am not sure about the others.

1. These attributes will be set as required on the table `eav_attribute` so what you can do here is create a setup script that updates the attributes so that they are not required.
2. Perform a rewrite of the model `Mage_Customer_Model_Address` and rewrite the function `_basicCheck`. Then include or only the validation that your required. For versions 1.8 and lower you will need to rewrite the function `validate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a `VarienForm()` being run on the page somewhere, it will instantiate the Prototype validation. It is usually in the format `var foobar = new VarienForm('foobar-form');` where `<form id="foobar-form"...`

It should be safe to comment out this function being called if you want to create your own with your own Javascript validation.

Comment: I still want to validate Phone number there. That's why I said "few fields". Actually I'd like to override Mage/Customer/Model/Adress/Abstract.php function validate() where you got these fields:
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = $helper->__('Please enter the city.');
        }

Answer (score 0):

For client side only, simply remove class "required-entry" from input element that you don't want any Javascript form validation.

With input validation:

```
<input id="firstname" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" maxlength="255" title="First Name" value="" name="firstname"></input>
```

Without:

```
<input id="firstname" class="input-text" type="text" maxlength="255" title="First Name" value="" name="firstname"></input>
```

Comment: this won't work because the address is validated server side also.